# Date Logic for a Post Date Invoice

Tags: sql-server-2008, date, logic, case

new to this site so trying to do my best to follow the instructions when asking questions. I am creating a report and having trouble with a date I have to pull in called Post Date. This date should return in the report as the 25th of the invoice month if the invoice date is on the 25th or before. If the invoice date is after the 25th of the month, I need the postdate to reflect the 25th of the next month. I have been trying case statements but having no luck.

This is the line I am using currently:

```
case 
    when (DAY(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE) < 26)
        then (Month(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE + '/25' + Year(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE)))
    else DATEADD(MM, 1, CT.HLSInvoiceDate) + '/25' + YEAR(CT.HLSInvoiceDate)
    end as [Post Date]
```

For example if my invoice date is 2/17/07 I want the Post Date to be 2/25/17, however if the invoice date is 2/26/17 I want the Post Date to be 3/25/17. Thanks for any help in advance. I am getting a conversion error when trying to do this. I am using SQLServer 2008 R2. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Below query should give you the expected result.

```
SELECT case 
    when (DAY(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE) < 26)
        then CAST(Month(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE)as varchar(2)) + '/25/' + CAST(Year(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE) as varchar(4))
    else CAST((Month(CT.HLSINVOICEDATE)+1 )as varchar(2)) + '/25/' + CAST(YEAR(CT.HLSInvoiceDate) as varchar(4))
    end as [Post Date]
```